# Skia hit-test with SkBounder

Tags: c++, google-chrome, onclick, chromium, skia

As used in `DebugHitTestBounder` in **SampleApp**; I have subclassed `SkBounder` and installed in my **canvas** (created in each draw) in order to find what is drawn under mouse clicks but the `onIRect` method is never called by the drawing routines. The `commit` method is called as expected (but I don't need it, I need one with a display-space converted rectangle parameter). I debugged the code, found out draw loops are managed in *canvas.cpp* in one place with macros (*LOOPER_BEGIN* and *LOOPER_END*) and found no place in the drawing calls that calls bounder's onIRect. Am I doing something **wrong?**

Note:  I am using code from 2 months old master branch of git repo with XCode 4.6 in Mac OS 10.8.x. Project files are created via gyp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `SkBounder` only works on the raster backend, I was using the accelerated (GL) backend.